# Override flask url prefix

Tags: python, url, flask

I have a Blueprint with a number of routes, which instantiates with a url_prefix option:

```
myxyz = Blueprint('xyz', __name__, url_prefix='/xyz')
```

This works for all the routes, no problem. However, one route in the blueprint does not need this prefix, but is still part of the blueprint.

Is there a way to override the prefix in the route definition within a blueprint?

EDIT:

There does not seem to be an immediate way, the quick workaround was to hardcode the prefix into all the routes that needed it, the reverse of what I'm asking (but works for now).

Comment: Can I ask why you're giving url_prefix to the blueprint, and not when attaching the blueprint to the application? `app.register_blueprint(myxyz, url_prefix='/xyz')`

Comment: May be you could not do the url_prefix while defining the blueprint and just add the url rule to individual view functions. This will be fine if you have a limited number of view functions.

Comment: The url_prefix is there because that is where I defined the blueprint, it is easier to define it there than when I pass the blueprint to the app factory to be registered on the app. Seems as though it does not really matter, but administratively seems cleaner to me to do it with the blueprint itself.

Comment: I did it the other way around for now: defining the prefix for all routes that need the prefix, omitting 'url_prefix=xyz' in the definition. There doesn't seem to be an 'override prefix' with route definition or down to werkzeug Rule definition.

Comment: You might want to look into subclassing werkzeug Rule.